# Why does winfr not recover anything?

Tags: windows, data-recovery

I have deleted a folder using Shift + Del. Now I need a .py file in it back.
The folder was located in `C:\Users\René\` but when I run
`winfr C: D: /n "\Users\René\"`, or even more specific, including the folder and file name, nothing gets recovered. Same goes for segment recovery using `/r`. Running `winfr C: D: /n *.py` does not help either.

`C:` is the only SSD with size 500 GB on my Laptop and `D:` is a USB Stick.

There was not much data written in the mean time, just installed 3 rather small programs including winfr.

The "Recovery_..." folder on `D:` is created and shows the log file which shows 0 recovered files.

Does this mean that my file cannot be recovered this way or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Files recovery is tricky, fragments of the file must exist, in order for any software recovery software to work.  If nothing is being recovered, then those fragments, likely no longer exist.  File recovery is highly dependent on how many files were written after the file was deleted, the time table ie extremely accelerated, when we are talking about SSDs due to the nature of the controller.

Comment: `winfr C: D: /n *.docx` would be the correct syntax to find any .docx file on the system drive and recover it on the specified drive.  Without knowing anything about the file you deleted, I cannot determine, if `winfr` is even the correct tool.  You should clarify your question by editing it and provide the required information to write a high quality answer.

Comment: Tried all this already. Does not recover anything. I deleted the file 3 days ago.

Comment: @Ramhound The Logfile also says 0 Damaged or irrecoverable files. Basically I am looking for a .py file which I had in a tree like this `\PyCharm Projects\tictactoe\tictactoe.py`.

Comment: How big is the drive? How much free space is on it? Is it encrypted? How much data do you think has been written since deletion? Did you install winfr [or anything else]  after this deletion?

Comment: So you ran the conman but used *.py instead?  As I have said you really should clarify the question by editing it.  You have not done that.  Try the command I suggested but run it against *.py instead of *.docx

Comment: Winfr does recover files, but nowodays SSDs have encryption active. I assume that's why my recovery didn't work from Samsung SSD 860 EVO. I accidently deleted some images and movies and although they were all recovered successfuly, every single one of them is unreadbale.

Answer (score 0):

The py file extension is filtered by default.
Can be disabled by the /e switch.

See documentation here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/recover-lost-files-on-windows-10-61f5b28a-f5b8-3cc2-0f8e-a63cb4e1d4c4

Comment: While this is true, specifying the `/e` option still doesn't recover file for me.